# Is it unusual for Google to take more than five days to include a new site in the search index?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, search

I recently launched a brand new website. It's a travel guide with around 260 unique pages with lots of newly written content and unique images.

I submitted the site to Google 5 days ago and at the same time, I submitted a sitemap. Fairly instantly, Google WMT showed that hundreds of pages had been crawled. But today it still shows that zero pages have been indexed. If I run a `site:www.site.com` search on Google I get around 20 results from my website. There seems to be no logic to which pages are ranked – there's a mix of posts, pages and category pages.

Should I just sit tight and wait longer or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2):

It will take time for Google to start properly indexing your website, as it is still processing your content and "figuring you out". This kind of behaviour is common with newly-submitted websites. One or two pages are indexed and they show up on Google (mostly, under **very** specific search queries). Then they disappear. Then they reappear.

All of this common. When it comes to Google, you have to be patient.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for replying and for putting my mind at rest. 

Appreciate your help.